# Convert awkwardly formatted excel data into tabular format using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing records for each day of the month. Unfortunately, the dataset has been formatted in an awkward way, making it difficult to analyse. I would like to restructure the data into a tabular format with columns for the date, venues, and the corresponding quantity under each heading. I've attached images of the current format as well as the desired output.

**Current Format**

```
             0    1       2    3       4    5       6    7       8    9
0   01/01/2023  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
1       Venue1  QTY  Venue2  QTY  Venue3  QTY  Venue4  QTY  Venue5  QTY
2            A    0       A    0       A    1       A    0       A    0
3            B   17       B    3       B   11       B    3       B    0
4            C    0       C    0       C    1       C    0       C    0
5            D    0       D    0       D   29       D    0       D    0
6            E    0       E    0       E    0       E    0       E    0
7            F    0       F    0       F    0       F    0       F    0
8            G    0       G    0       G    0       G    0       G    0
9            H    0       H    0       H    0       H    0       H    0
10  02/01/2023  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
11      Venue1  QTY  Venue2  QTY  Venue3  QTY  Venue4  QTY  Venue5  QTY
12           A    0       A    0       A    1       A    0       A    0
13           B   11       B    3       B    0       B    6       B    2
14           C    0       C    0       C    0       C    0       C    0
15           D   20       D    0       D   28       D    0       D   24
16           E    0       E    0       E    0       E    0       E    0
17           F    0       F    0       F    0       F    0       F    0
18           G    0       G    0       G    0       G    0       G    0
19           H    0       H    0       H    0       H    0       H    0
```

[image: Current Format]

**Required Format**

[image: Required Format]

I've tried manipulating in pandas, but i'm not sure how to go about it exactly to get the the desired result. Any suggestions or sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: This question feels a little broad in it's current form. Questions on stackoverflow focus on a specific question about code you are writing. Can you share what you have written so far by editing the question, copy/pasting code, highlight what's pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve whitespace and line feeds. It may help to briefly read [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for tips on what code to share and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with [*pandas reshaping*](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html) :

```
tmp = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None)

m = pd.to_datetime(tmp[0], errors="coerce").notnull()

blocks = {n: g.set_axis(g.iloc[0], axis=1).iloc[1:]
          for n,g in tmp.loc[~m].groupby(tmp[0].where(m).ffill())}
df = (
    pd.concat(blocks, names=["Date"])
        .assign(Venues= lambda x: x["Venue1"])
        .pipe(lambda x: x.set_axis(
            [f"{col}" if i%2 == 0 else f"QTY_{x.columns[i-1]}"
             for i, col in enumerate(x.columns)], axis=1))
        .filter(regex="QTY.+|Venues").set_index("Venues", append=True)
     .rename(lambda x: x.split("_")[1], axis=1).droplevel(1).unstack(1)
     .stack(0).reset_index(names=["Date", "Venues"]).rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

         Date  Venues  A   B  C   D  E  F  G  H
0  01/01/2023  Venue1  0  17  0   0  0  0  0  0
1  01/01/2023  Venue2  0   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
2  01/01/2023  Venue3  1  11  1  29  0  0  0  0
3  01/01/2023  Venue4  0   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
4  01/01/2023  Venue5  0   0  0   0  0  0  0  0
5  02/01/2023  Venue1  0  11  0  20  0  0  0  0
6  02/01/2023  Venue2  0   3  0   0  0  0  0  0
7  02/01/2023  Venue3  1   0  0  28  0  0  0  0
8  02/01/2023  Venue4  0   6  0   0  0  0  0  0
9  02/01/2023  Venue5  0   2  0  24  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance this has been extremely helpful.  How can I modify the code to include all dates from a dataset, even if the number of days varies, so that they are displayed in the final output dataframe? Currently, when I run the code, only the first two dates are returned in the dataframe.

Comment: You’re welcome ;) This code is generic and should grab all the dates/blocks but if you tell me that’s not the case, I’ll check that as soon as possible because I’m AFK right now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I added a third block with `03/01/2023` as a data (*see* https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPKNA.png) and I got a correct result (*see* https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpz46.png).